# Is there a way to save multiple variables in python pickle?

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to save multiple variables to a file. E.G saving an item in a shop so I'm trying to save the items price,name and code to one file, and multiple items to the same file

```
def enter_item_info():
count = 0
count1 = 0
print("how many items are you entering?")
amount = int(input("Items = "))
data = [[0,1,2]] * amount




file = (open('fruit.txt','wb'))
while count < amount:




    data[0 + count1][0] = input("Code")


    data[0 + count1][1] = input("NAme")

    data[0 + count1][2] = input("Price")
    count1 = count1 + 1
    count = count + 1


    print("")



pickle.dump(data , file)
file.close()
amount = str(amount)
file1 = (open('amount.txt','wb'))
pickle.dump(amount , file1)
file1.close()
```

Comment: What did you try, what problems came up?

Comment: Your code is not properly indented - please make sure all indentation is as it should be, as this is rather important in Python.

Answer (score 14):

You definitely can save multiple objects to a pickle file, either by putting the objects in a collection (like a list or dict) and then pickling the collection, or by using multiple entries in a pickle file… or both.

```
>>> import pickle
>>> fruits = dict(banana=0, pear=2, apple=6)
>>> snakes = ['cobra', 'viper', 'rattler']
>>> with open('stuff.pkl', 'wb') as f:
...   pickle.dump(fruits, f)
...   pickle.dump(snakes, f)
... 
>>> with open('stuff.pkl', 'rb') as f:
...   food = pickle.load(f)
...   pets = pickle.load(f)
... 
>>> food
{'pear': 2, 'apple': 6, 'banana': 0}
>>> pets
['cobra', 'viper', 'rattler']
>>>
```

Comment: So load sequentially grabs an item in the same order as they were dumped?

Comment: @brethvoice: yes.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) (emphasis on the `==>`):

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> ```
> None, True, and False
> integers, long integers, floating point numbers, complex numbers
> normal and Unicode strings
> ===> tuples, lists, sets, and dictionaries containing only picklable objects
> functions defined at the top level of a module
> built-in functions defined at the top level of a module
> classes that are defined at the top level of a module
> instances of such classes whose __dict__ or the result of calling __getstate__() is picklable (see section The pickle protocol for details).
> ```

So you can store all your data in lists and/or dictionnary and you should be fine.